# Customizing AreaNavigationSettings.aspx

Tags: 2007

When you click Modify Navigation we will be able to see AreaNavigationSettings.aspx, where we will be able to customize the CurrentNavigation and GlobalNavigation. i want to include a new node of Navigation in the tree for eg: SecondLevelNavigation, Where i will attach a provider and should be able to hide/Add link using the tree control.

Is there any way i could achieve this / or is there any other solution

Thanks in Advance

Thomson

Answer (score 1):

This page is a _Layouts page, so you can't modify it without invalidating your support :/

What you could do is build your own page for this (copying the existing one is fine), then use a feature with CustomActions to remove and replace the links to the current page with links to the new page you're creating.

However, you're likely to have to write your own version of the HierarchicalListBox - which is in the microsoft.sharepoint.publishing.internal.webcontrols namespace. It's internal, and largely undocumented - if could be tricky.